# WebAPI 2 file upload works in develop, gives 404 in production

Tags: iis, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2

I've developed a fileupload tool (using nervgh fileupload for angularjs) that works fine in development. The file(s) are send to a WebApi upload controller:

```
   public class UploadController : ApiController
{       
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
    {
        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\" + Properties.Settings.Default.uploadDir);
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        var documentNewDir = "";
        var documentRelative = "";
        var fileName = "";

        try
        {
            // Read the form data.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            // This illustrates how to get the file names.
            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                var vergaderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(provider.FormData["vergaderdatum"]);
                var jaar = vergaderDate.Year;
                var maand= vergaderDate.Month.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).PadLeft(2, '0');
                var dag =vergaderDate.Day.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).PadLeft(2, '0');

                //absolute path to documents new dir
                documentNewDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") + Properties.Settings.Default.documentsBaseDir + @"\" + jaar + @"\" + maand + @"\" + dag;

                //filename
                fileName = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);

                //relativePath and filename
                documentRelative = Properties.Settings.Default.documentsBaseDir + @"/" + jaar + @"/" + maand + @"/" + dag + @"/"+ fileName;


                if(!Directory.Exists(documentNewDir))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(documentNewDir);
                File.Move(file.LocalFileName, documentNewDir + @"\"+fileName);
            }

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, documentRelative);
            return response;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }

}
```

This works fine in a development setting but deployed to a MS 2012 server IIS 8.5 production server i get an 404 on the POST API call to api/upload.

The application support some other WebAPI calls that worke fine in both dev/prod environments.... How can i start to investigate/debug this situation?

Here's the call in Fiddler ( left out the filedata....):

```
-----------------------------7df2b09e0350
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="vergaderdatum"

2015-01-30T00:00:00
 -----------------------------7df2b09e0350
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="5.0. Vooraankondiging themabijeenkomstSamen naar Buiten, 17 sept.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.5
%âãÏÓ
```

and the response

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Jan 2015 15:31:08 GMT
Content-Length: 1245
```

Comment: Try using Fiddler or Postman (for Chrome) to compose and send a POST request to your Upload/PostFormData action, and see what you get. If you get a 404, your action is not being invoked. If you get a 500 it's the action's answer. I recommned Postmand: it's much more intuitive to compose a post that Fiddler... unless you've used Fiddler on other occassions

Comment: editted the call with fiddler data

Comment: Please, compose a request by yourself, don't capture a file post in fiddler. I know it will not content a file. Hopefully the response will give us a pointer to the next move

Comment: You mean a plain POST or GET to the API?

Comment: Get ( in Postman) results in: Method not allowed and POST ( whithout a file attached) gives a 415 unsupported media type

Comment: The GET behavior is as expected. And the POST behavior is interesting: it looks like `PostFormData` is being invoked, and the 415 is the error you're returning from your method. Can you change the method to return something else, redeploy the app, and run the test again to ensure that it's your method's response? If we confirm this, we now that the method can be invoked, and have to look somewhere else for the problem. Next step would be to include the payload (file) in the POST request (in Postman), and check if it's still successful or what happens in that case.

Comment: After adding a header in Postman with multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7df2b06140a2e ( a boundary copied from a succesfull call in dev) the POST was accepted but generated an error on that invalid boundary ( because it was copied from another instance) so it seems that the issue is the missing boundary coding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68864/discussion-between-jotabe-and-john-westhoff).

Answer (score 1):

I'VE FOUND THE ERROR!
in production the website was installed as a subdomain of the default website. In the javascript was a reference to the upload method (/api/upload) after i added the name of the subdomain like /bisbeheer/api/upload in the javascript it uploaded the file